# Algorithm of likes

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, algorithm

Come to develop a small tanned algorithm logic and need help from someone to be able to finish it! Let's look at the code:

```
function likesresults($user_like,$total_like, $postid){

  if($user_like == 1 && $total_like == 1){
    $resposta_like = '<span id="you'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'"><a href="#">You</a> like this.</span>';
  }

  if ($user_like == 1 && $total_like >= 2) {
    $sub_like = $total_like-1;
  if($sub_like -3 == 0) {
  } else {
    $total = $sub_like - 3;
    $resto = ', and others '.$total.'';
  }
  $resposta_like = '<span id="you'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'"><a href="#">You</a>, user1,user2,user3,user4'.$resto.' like this.';
  }

  if ($user_like == 0 && $total_like >= 1) {
    if($total_like -3 == 0) {
    } else {
      $total = $sub_like - 3;
      $resto = ', and others '.$total.'';
    }
    $resposta_like = 'user1,user2,user3,user4'.$resto.' like this.';
  }

  if($total_like == 0){
    $resposta_like = "";
  }

  return  $resposta_like;
}
```

It is simple and easy to understand, the problem is that I would like to show 4 users who also likes such content, and leave in order of "friendship", for example if the user likes it X1, beauty!, Displays it, but if X2 what the user likes and besides all still friends of the logged in user he has to appear before the X1, they are friends!, understood what I meant? I'm too lost in the logic of how to make this work, please give me a light, already thanks!

Resume: I would just like to list who likes that sort who likes content and order of friendship with the logged in user, ie who is friend appears before those who are not, as well as on facebook. .

Comment: I cannot comprehend your last paragraph. I'd suggest you rewrite it to make it clearer.

Comment: Sorry I'm not very good, but I'll try to summarize, I would just like to list who likes that sort who likes content and order of friendship with the logged in user, ie who is friend appears before those who are not, as well as on facebook. .